# Issue with array_agg method when aggregating arrays of different lengths

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Here is a lateral query which is part of a bigger query:

```
lateral (
    select 
    array_agg(
            sh.dogsfilters
        ) filter (
            where 
                sh.dogsfilters is not null
        ) as dependencyOfFoods
    from 
        shelter sh
    where 
        sh.shelterid = ${shelterid}
) filtersOfAnimals,
```

the problem is with `array_agg` method as it fails when it has arrays with different lengths like this `("[[7, 9], [7, 9, 8], [8]]")`!

The problem is easy to solve using `json_agg` but later in the query there's a `any` check like this:

```
...
where
    cd.dogsid = any(filtersOfAnimals.dependencyOfFoods)
and 
    ...
...
```

But as `any` will not work on json data which is prepared using `json_agg` so I can't use it instead of `array_agg`!

What might be a better solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unnest the arrays and re-aggregate:

```
lateral
(select array_agg(dogfilter) filter (where dogfilter is not null) as dependencyOfFoods
 from shelter sh cross join
      unnest(sh.dogsfilters) dogfilter
 where sh.shelterid = ${shelterid}
) filtersOfAnimals,
```

It is interesting that Postgres doesn't have a function that does this.  BigQuery offers `array_concat_agg()` which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It is ugly, but it works:

```
regexp_split_to_array(
          array_to_string(
             array_agg(
              array_to_string(value,',')
              ),','
          ),',')::integer[]
```

I don't know if this could be a valid solution from the the performance point of view ...

Comment: Converting an array to a string to convert back to an array of integers just doesn't seem like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, you can define your own aggregates.  I think that this one does what you want:

```
create function array_concat_agg_tran(anyarray,anyarray) returns anyarray language sql
    as $$ select $1||$2 $$;
create aggregate array_concat_agg(anyarray) (sfunc=array_concat_agg_tran, stype=anyarray);
```

Then:

```
 select array_concat_agg(x) from (values (ARRAY[1,2]),(ARRAY[3,4,5])) f(x);
 array_concat_agg 
------------------
 {1,2,3,4,5}
```

With a bit more work, you could make it parallelizable as well.

Comment: The more I know about PostgreSQL the more it amazes me! Thanks for the details.